# How to get protocol in ActiveMQ Artemis via JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm sending a message to an Artemis ActiveMQ queue, but I can't find a method to get the message protocol

Code for receiving the body of the message, but in this class I did not find a method for obtaining the protocol:

```
connectQueueBrowser();
Enumeration<Message> messageEnumeration =  queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
while (messageEnumeration.hasMoreElements()){
   messages.add(messageEnumeration.nextElement());
}
System.out.println(messages.get(0).getBody(String.class));
```

The Message class is in the package:
`import javax.jms.Message;`

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to get the protocol of the sender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't store the which protocol *sent* the message. The `protocol` value that you see when inspecting a message via management regards how the message is **stored on disk**. The broker supports 2 different storage formats:

- one for messages sent via AMQP (i.e. `AMQP`)
- one for messages sent via every *other* protocol (i.e. `CORE`).

There is no way to retrieve this data from any supported JMS `Message` implementation.

It's worth noting that one of the main design elements of asynchronous messaging is a 100% decoupling of producers and consumers. In other words, producers don't care (and don't know) about consumers and consumers don't care (and don't know) about producers. Furthermore, in a properly decoupled application the consumer **shouldn't care** about what protocol was used to send the message. It should only care about the data in the message, regardless of how it was sent.